# Trouble connecting S3 Bucket (EU-Region) to LocomotiveCMS on heroku

Tags: amazon-s3, locomotivecms

I have trouble connecting my locomotiveCMS engine on heroku with my S3 Bucket. I have a EU-Region Bucket and set the heroku vars as following:

```
S3_BUCKET: assets.mydomain.de
S3_BUCKET_REGION: eu-west-1
```

With this setup I get an Error in my HTML Source and the assets won't upload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><RequestId>AB6E67D9D5B88B65</RequestId><Bucket>assets.mydomain.de</Bucket><HostId>sZB988g5ap7FKNoliaAWros5J3aHApHVzmj4dvEhD0OPonJE9I5Oxxn5u6L6j2g7</HostId><Endpoint>assets.mydomain.de.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint></Error>
```

Are ther any known Issues with EU-Buckets?

Answer (score 0):

The s3 bucket is just a name, not a domain name.
In the s3 console management, what is the bucket name you've created?

Comment: I assume that the bucket is named after a domain name -- I often use that approach.